# is this valid js argument?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure I am writing valid javascript argument or not.

```
function localData(){

    this.setInfo(key, value) =  
            function(){
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            };
}
```

how can I post key, value params in setInfo(key, value) to function(){}? 
 
is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: If you didn't include `localData`, would the question still make sense? If so, please don't include it.

Comment: Only properties and variables are valid on the left-hand-side (LHS) of the assignment operator. (That is a function-application on the LHS and thus not a property or variable and thus not valid. It will result in a SyntaxError.)

Comment: What do you think `this` references inside the function? Is `localData` supposed to be a constructor?

Comment: yes. localData is a constructor. I wanted this function to act like class in java. ex) var a = new localData(); a.setInfo("123","abc");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's say correct is:

```
function localData(){
 setInfo = function(key, value) {
   localStorage.setItem(key, value);
 }
}
```

Comment: Should probably be `this.setInfo = ...` (assuming `localData` is called as constructor function).

Comment: so.. if I write setInfo("abc", "123"); key : abc , value : 123 will be stored in localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `localData` is the function in which you want to define `setInfo` in such a way that you can call it with two arguments -- `key` and `value`. Try this:

```
this.setInfo = function (key, value) {
    // whatever code here
}
```

Remember, functions are objects too!